# How do you determine point groups of more complex molecules when there are 2 or more central atoms?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

I am trying to determine the point group of Fe2(CO)8 and am having difficulty with the bond angles and geometry. How would one go about this in a logical sense?

Comment: Find the center of mass (which must be preserved by any symmetry operation) and go through the process as if it were the central atom, even if there is no atom at that exact place.

Comment: As an aside note that you can pick any point as an origin, its just that you will also in general have to include translators over and above the normal operations that are taught. But for molecular systems there always exists a point such that if chosen as the origin the number of required translators is zero, resulting in what is usually taught for chemists;  @IvanNeretin has given the recipe. Also note that  for periodic system, such as crystals, this is not the case. I doubt this is a big surprise.

Comment: Have a look at this site https://molecule-viewer.com/ where you can add symmmetry elements (rotation axes, reflection planes etc.) and test your skill at finding the point group.

Answer (score 2):

The determination of the point group of a molecule does not mandate the presence of one atom in the centre of the molecule.  Indeed you can assign point group symmetries to objects other than molecules, e.g. the [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid), polyhedra in general (see Kai Landskron's synopsis on [chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Centre_College/CHE_332%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry/03%3A_Molecular_Symmetry_and_Point_Groups/3.02%3A_Point_Groups), for example), and objects of the daily life (coffee mug, pair of scissors, Allen key, the barrel of revolving doors, propellers, tires of cars by different manufactures, etc.)

In addition to building molecular models, the compilation of materials on [Symmetry@Otterbein](https://symotter.org/) includes a [gallery](https://symotter.org/gallery) which not only allows you to toggle on/off highlights of the symmetry operators, but to see their application *which can be halted to «walk around» the molecule*.  As an example about naphthalene ($D_\text{2h}$) and one of its $C_2$ axes (note, there is *no* atom at the mass centre of the molecule):

[image]

If you happen to have the geometry of your compound in a format accessible e.g. to [Jmol](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Main_Page), the assignment of the point group symmetry and the subsequent display of the operators can be relayed (while retaining a critical eye on it) to a program, too.  As an example, $\ce{Fe2(CO)9}$ (a molecule different to the one of your question) from the program's console (file -> console) by the commands `compute pointgroup` followed by `draw pointgroup`:

[image]

(The relevant thresholds are adjustable, see `calculate pointgroup` in Jmol's [documentation](https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/docs/).)

Perhaps Bertini's paper hints to a reference file about $\ce{Fe2(CO)8}$ the abstracts describes as «dibriged $C_{2v}$ isomer for the singlet and the unbridged $D_{2d}$ isomer for the triplet.»

Bertini, L.; Bruschi, M.; De Gioia, L.; Fantucci, P. Structure and Energetics of $\ce{Fe2(CO)8}$ Singlet and Triplet Electronic States. *J. Phys. Chem. A* **2007**, *111*, 12152–12162, [doi 10.1021/jp075343z](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp075343z).